# Modifiers dont work properly after SVG Import and Curve to Mesh

Tags: svg

:)

I try to make a 3D object from a vector logo. But when i try to use modifiers they dont work properly.

Here my steps:

1. import SVG ➔ origin to geometry ➔ scale all up, rotate z&y ➔ apply all transformations.
2. remove the SVG material ➔ curve: fill mode: none ➔ resolution 24
3. convert to mesh
4. edit mode ➔ select all ➔ x: limited desolve, max angle: 0,1°
5. select all ➔ f: new face ➔ p: seperate the counter (holes in the S-form)

And now i try to use modifiers in this order: solidify, bevel, supdivision surface.
The solidify seems to work fine. In the bevel modifier i can't change the amount. And the supsurf looks like shit.

I also tried to make the faces by hand, this hasnt worked either. The seperated counters should be used later with a boolean.

I also checked the svg file. In Illustator the points look clean, there is no overlaping. Also in edit mode i can't find mistakes likes overlapping or something. I also tried extruding it in edit mode.

I think there is something obvious i dont see as a beginner. Maybe topology or something.

Here is the SVG I use:

```
https://svgshare.com/s/fqF
```

Hope you can help! :)

BR Phil

Answer (score 2):

I think the resulting geometry is just too complicated for Blender, mostly because of the single face with two holes.  Here's Geometry that doesn't go whacko when I add the modifiers:

[image: Geometry that works]

I didn't scale and rotate, because that wouldn't have made any difference and you didn't specify by how much.  You can do that with this geometry.

After I converted to mesh and removed the counter, I used the counter in a Boolean to create the holes and applied the boolean.  I deleted the resulting large single face and created the geometry you see here.

To go around the curves easily, I enabled the F2 addon, it's a built in and it allows this technique:

1. Select one vertex on the outside and inside at the edge of the curve.
2. Type <kbd>F</kbd> to create an edge between them.
3. Place the cursor so that it's in the direction you want to add faces.
4. Type <kbd>F</kbd> as many times as necessary to fill all of the faces in the curve.

I included the long diagonal edge and the quad that creates.

Next I selected all of the vertices surrounding the remaining empty part of the object and created a single face.  I repeated this on the bottom as well.

Finally, I used the knife tool to connect two of the vertices making a quad.  Doing this three more times, I ended up with all quad geometry.

Supporting images:

1. The empty geometry:

   [image: empty geometry]
2. The starting edge:

   [image: starting edge]
3. All of the faces created using the F2 tool for the first section:

   [image: first section]
4. All of the faces created using the F2 tool

[image: f2 tool]

1 The manual face on the bottom

[image: bottom manual face]

Comment: Wow, Thank you! I will try it tomorrow and tell you if it worked. but sounds like it would! :)

Comment: @PhilVonD. good luck.  I kind of rushed the explanation, so feel free to ask any questions that come up.

Comment: I tried your workflow and i have some questions.

1. What do you mean with
"I used the counter in a Boolean to create the holes and applied the boolean. I deleted the resulting large single face and created the geometry you see here."
Did you used the boolean before you solidify or extrude? When I try this the boolean don't work. Is this step necessary or could i use the mesh with the holes?

2. Is there a special way how you seperate the last face in three faces?

3. Did you tried to use a bevel modifier after you made the mesh? did the amount-slider work on your version?